# Python Error: IPython.display import Markdown as display

Tags: python, ipython, markdown, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to use the pydna module on a machine running Ubuntu 14.04, and am getting the following error when I try to import it:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydna/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pydna.amplify                                  import Anneal
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydna/amplify.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pydna.dsdna                    import rc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydna/dsdna.py", line 63, in <module>
    from IPython.display import Markdown as display
ImportError: cannot import name Markdown
```

Has anyone found a way to resolve this?  I have tried reinstalling IPython, and pydna.  The offending chunk in dsdna.py is the following:
(lines 58-63)

```
try:
    import IPython
except ImportError:
    def display(item): return item
else:
    from IPython.display import Markdown as display
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Python 2.7.6)

Comment: Is markdown installed? `pip install markdown` or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the IPython 4.1.1 installed and it works for me (see below). Which version do you have? Also, which pydna version did you install?

This could be due to a too old version of IPython, recently IPython was split into IPython and Jupyter which caused some code to break.

```
(bjorn)bjorn@bjorn-ThinkPad-T450s:~/Desktop/GMB$ python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:04:42) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from IPython.display import Markdown as display
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython.__version__
'4.1.1'
```

Comment: I had pydna1.0.0, and ipython1.4;  updating ipython got things working, thanks so much!